# Pyspark: Connection reset using toLocalIterator

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to iterate locally over rdd data using a loop like `for row in rdd.toLocalIterator():` in pyspark and I get this error:

```
19/03/21 17:01:36 ERROR PythonRDD: Error while sending iterator
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:515)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:527)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:527)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:527)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:728)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:728)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:728)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1340)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2.run(PythonRDD.scala:729)
```

It works well when I'm using `rdd.collect()` on a small table but uses too much memory for large datasets.

I already tried to increase `spark.driver.memory`, `spark.executor.memory` and `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval`.

version of Spark: 2.2.1

How can I fix this?

This is the minimal code I am using:

```
for source_row in rdd.toLocalIterator():
    print(source_row)
```

I have the same error with:

```
iterator = rdd.toLocalIterator()
next(iterator)
```

Comment: How many partitions do you currently have?

Comment: 180 partitions.

Comment: If you think one of the 180 could be big enough to fit in the memory of the driver then you could increase the partition number to 250 or even 500.

Comment: I tried to increase it, but I still have the error. The connection is reset after 7 seconds.

Comment: Could please post the complete code or the most significant part of it which involves toLocalIterator?

Comment: I added some code but I doubt it will help.

Comment: yes because the most useful part is missing that is the RDD population. How many partitions do you have at the moment?